# how to unlock all items that were locked by virtualssuser?

Tags: sql-database, content-management

How to unlock  items that were locked by **virtualssuser** sitecore 8.1 ?

query like it can't find any records about user in code database

```
SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE UserName like '%virtualssuser%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tried a poc on this before & we can  achieve it using fast query to unlock items locked by a specific user if you have reasonable number of items to be unlocked.

```csharp
Item[] items = database.SelectItems("fast:/sitecore/content//*[@__lock='%user=%']");
foreach (var item in items){
    item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    item.Locking.Unlock();
    item.Editing.EndEdit(); 
}
```